# Otimização de código

Tags: jquery, css, css3

Tenho uma **UL** gerada automaticamente através de um **SELECT OPTION**.

Na arquitetura que criei, tenho um **LABEL** que pega a primeira **OPTION** do **SELECT**. Este **LABEL** também será o responsável por receber o **click** que abrirá a **UL** abaixo ou acima dele dependendo de sua posição na página.

Com o código abaixo, eu verifico se a **LABEL** se encontra no final da área visível da página.

Caso esteja, então posiciono a **UL** sobre a **LABEL**, caso contrário posiciono a **UL** abaixo da **LABEL**.

Porém, estou achando este **código** muito **pobre**, com várias variáveis, e gostaria de saber de vocês se é possível melhorá-lo de alguma forma.

**HTML**

```
<div class="selectOptions">
  <select required>
    <option value="1">Um</option>
    <option value="2">Dois</option>
    <option value="3">Três</option>
    <option value="4">Quatro</option>
    <option value="5">Cinco</option>
    <option value="6">Seis</option>
    <option value="7">Sete</option>
    <option value="8">Oito</option>
  </select>
  <label class="selecionada"></label>
  <ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    // entrega o primeiro elemento da select option à div .selecionada
    $(".selectOptions .selecionada").html($(".selectOptions select > option:first-child").html());

    /*popula as li's*/
    $(".selectOptions select > option").each(function() {
        //Não exibe a primeira li pois esta já está sendo exibida na .selecionada
        if ($(this).is(':first-child')) $(".selectOptions ul").append("<li value='" + this.value + "' style='display:none;'>" + this.text + "</li>");
        else $(".selectOptions ul").append("<li style='display:block;' value='" + this.value + "'>" + this.text + "</li>");
    });

    //contador de vezes que abre e fecha a ul
    contador = 0;

    $(".selectOptions .selecionada").click(function(e) {

        quantasLis = $(".selectOptions ul li").length;

        if (contador % 2 == 0) {

            $(".selectOptions .selecionada").addClass("setaCima").removeClass("setaBaixo");
            $(".selectOptions ul").css("display", "block");
            $(".selectOptions ul li").css("display", "none").slideDown(400);

            if (quantasLis > 4) {
                $(".selectOptions ul").css('height', '175px');
                $(".selectOptions ul").css("overflow-y", "scroll");
            } else {
                $(".selectOptions ul").css('height', (quantasLis*35)+'px');
                $(".selectOptions ul").css("overflow-y", "auto");
            }

            janela = $(window).height();

            selecionadaPosicao = $(".selectOptions .selecionada").offset().top;
            selecionadaAltura = $(".selectOptions .selecionada").height();
            ulAltura = $(".selectOptions ul").height();
            janelaScroll = $(window).scrollTop(); // distância que a página foi rolada

            posicaoFinal = ulAltura + $(".selectOptions .selecionada").outerHeight();

            total = selecionadaPosicao + selecionadaAltura + ulAltura - janelaScroll;

            if (total >= janela)
                $(".selectOptions ul").css("bottom", posicaoFinal, "important");
            else             
                $(".selectOptions ul").css("bottom", "0", "important");


        } else {

            $(".selectOptions .selecionada").addClass("setaBaixo").removeClass("setaCima");
            $(".selectOptions ul li").slideUp(400, function() {
                $(".selectOptions ul").css("overflow-y", "hidden");
            });
        }

        contador++;

        e.stopPropagation();

    });

    /*ai clicar na li, busca correspondência na select option e o checa (marca)*/
    $('.selectOptions ul li').on('click', function(evt) {
        /*Joga a li selecionada na label .selecionada*/
        $(".selectOptions .selecionada").html($(this).html());
        /*Joga a li selecionada ao topo da ul*/
        $($(this).closest('ul')).prepend($(this));
        // Armazena nome do maos que quer selecionar
        var li = $(this).attr("value");
        // Guarda em opcao o elemento que retornar do filtro que vai testar entre as
        // options possÃ­veis
        var opcao = $('.selectOptions select option').filter(function() {
            // testa entre as options qual delas tem o mesmo conteÃºdo que o desejado
            return $(this).attr('value') === li;
        });
        // Redefine o atributo do elemento encontrado pra selecionado.
        opcao.attr('selected', true);

    });

    // ao clicar em qualquer coissa, fecha a ul caso ela esteja aberta
    $(document).on('click', function(e) {
        if (
            $(".selectOptions ul").css("overflow-y") == "auto" ||
            $(".selectOptions ul").css("overflow-y") == "scroll") {
            $(".selectOptions .selecionada").trigger("click");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Te aconselho a segmentar mais as perguntas, perguntando uma coisa de cada vez e criando novas perguntas.

Comment: Alterado! @LéoCunha