# SlideDown de baixo para cima

Tags: jquery, css, css3

Gostaria de aplicar efeito **slideDown()**, em uma **UL**, porém gostaria que o efeito corresse de baixo para cima. Isto é, que a **div** abrisse de baixo para cima.

Comment: Já tentou com slideUp()?

Answer (score 2):

O [slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) embora possa parecer a solução apenas esconde o elemento, como podemos ver na documentação:

> Description: Hide the matched elements with a sliding motion.

E por isso não irá servir para o que pretende. Pode resolver o problema utilizando o [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) e aumentando o `height`.

Exemplo:

```js
let direcao = "+";

$("button").on("click", function(){
  $("#d1").animate({height: direcao + "=50px"}, 1000);
  $(this).text(direcao == "-" ? "Mostrar Div" : "Fechar Div");
  direcao = direcao == "+" ? "-" : "+";
});
```

```css
#d1 {
  background-color:cyan;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d1"></div>
<button>Mostrar Div</button>
```

Para fazer como que não dependa de um tamanho fixo pode fazer um aumento incremental com:

```
height: "+=50px"
```

Que aumenta `50px` ao tamanho que tem, ou diminuir com:

```
height: "-=50px"
```

Comment: **E por isso não irá servir para o que pretende** Como assim? Ele não referiu que não queria esconder. Apenas queria algo como `slideDown()`.

Comment: @I_like_trains "a div abrisse de baixo para cima" faz me interpretar como abrir e não esconder. Poderei ter interpretado mais do que o AP disse mas é certamente algo que ele poderá esclarecer.

Comment: Sim, o que eu quero é só abrir a div de baixo para cima, não esconde-la. Vou estudar esse efeito porque é isso mesmo que preciso. O detalhe é que tenho uma label e a lista, às vezes abrirá abaixo da label, às vezes abrirá acima. Quando abaixo, o slideDown() resolve, mas quando acima, então não pois ficará estranho uma lista abrir de cima para baixo estado por acima da label que recebe o click de abre e fecha.Código completo aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/245333/otimiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo

Comment: Não consegui adaptar ao meu script.

Comment: @CarlosRocha Se conseguir montar um JSFiddle com o problema talvez consiga ajudar.

Comment: Vou fazer melhor: http://hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/, uma select que tem no fim da pagina

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yscLh64g/2/

Comment: @CarlosRocha Mas que parte é que deveria animar para cima ? E como ? A lista fecha mal se clica em qualquer elemento da lista

Comment: Então, note que, no site, se você posicionar a select no final da página, as options abrem para cima da caixa da select. Percebeu? Bem, note que o efeito de slideDown() ocorre de cima para baixo. O que eu quer é o contrário, que o slideDown() ocorresse de baixo para cima. Mas não é fechar o select, é abrir mesmo. Quando o select está em uma parte da páginas em que, se abrir a caixa com as options, ela caiba antes do fim da pagina, então as options abrem abaixo da caixa, caso contrário, a caixa com as options abre acima

Comment: @CarlosRocha Mas no fiddle que colocou aqui a lista está no topo logo nem daria para abrir para cima. Para além disso você faz slideDown, aqui: `$(".selectOptions ul li").css("display", "none").slideDown(400);`. Se quer abrir para cima não poderá fazer slideDown e sim uma implementação manual sua com `animate` ou `css` alterando o `height` de forma semelhante à minha resposta

Comment: sim, testa no site por favor?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yscLh64g/3/

Comment: Então, tentei usar o seu script mas não funcionou. Na verdade não consegui.

Comment: @CarlosRocha Você quer abrir diferente dependendo do sitio onde está ? Bem complicado se quer a minha opinião. Bastante código para pouco sumo. Mas terá que interpretar a posição da janela em relação ao elemento com `$(window).scrollTop` e ter duas funções diferentes de abertura uma para cada caso. E ainda é capaz de ter problemas na mesma se a pessoa abrir o `select` com ele no fim e acabar por andar para cima e fechar jà com ele a meio. De qualquer forma é um problema diferente do que está aqui na pergunta

Comment: Essa parte da posição do select já funciona.Falta só mesmo fazer abrir de baixo para cima com animate() que eu não fui capaz de fazer. Pode conferir aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/yscLh64g/3/

Comment: @CarlosRocha Certamente que não está como quer mas comentei quase tudo deixando o minimo para mostrar a aplicação do animate, para que possa ver: [https://jsfiddle.net/bx99rbtz/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/bx99rbtz/2/). O principio é basear-se na altura da lista (ul) e não em `display:block`/`none`. Significa que ela está sempre visivel mas com `height:0` e `overflow:hidden`, a partir dai é meramente alterar o height para mostrar ou esconder

Comment: Ok, então onde errei agora? https://jsfiddle.net/yscLh64g/4/

Comment: @CarlosRocha acontece que a `label` está por cima do `ul` logo o efeito está certo mas parece visualmente incorreto pois ao aumentar o tamanho do `ul` sobe a `label` qie está em cima. Isso já é posicionamento e pode alterar de varias formas, desde modificar a ordem no html, alterar o posicionamento para fixed/absolute no CSS, etc..

Comment: Então, se não for pedir demais, altera para min no jsfiddle.net e crie um novo funcionando?

Answer (score 0):

Use o `.slideUp()`, faz o o oposto do `slideDown()`.